# Changing employer with a new EU blue card after 3.5 years of working in France

Tags: france, blue-card

I have three questions, but a little explanations first. Currently I have a Talent Passport for young innovative company, it still has validity for another 1.5 year and I've been working for more than two years under it. That means my visa is not tied to my current employer anymore and I can work for other employers and jobs that meet the condition. Also I can quit without any job lined up and have the right to stay in France until the end of its validity (At least that is what I think).

But now our previous company is being bough by a bigger company, and my contract is moved to the new company. They are asking me to enter a new process to get "Talent Passport EU Blue Card", because they are not considered as innovative company. But from what I've gathered, if I do that I'll be tied to my current employer for another 2 years before being able to change employer. Also I cannot quit, if I do I need to leave the country in three months. Those are my assumptions but I don't know if they are true.

1- Can't my new employer just use my old visa, because my visa is not tied to any employer now, they just need to ask for a work permit?

2- Given that I've already worked for 3.5 years in France and paid taxes, can I change employee under 2 years of working for this employer with a new blue card?

3- Can my blue card act as a residence permit? What happens if I quit without any job lined up? How long can I stay in France to look for another job with new Blue card?